# The Domain of a Quotient with a Rational Function

Tags: functions

The function is $f(x)=\frac{x+1}{1+\frac1{x+1}}$. It's natural to say the domain is $\Bbb R\setminus\{-2,-1\}$.

However:

In this case, $f(-1)=\frac0{1\pm\infty}$ (throw in a limit if it makes you feel better) would unambiguously be 0, so this looks like a nice continuous function at $x=-1$ to me.

**What is the domain of this function? (and why?)**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The domain of $f$ is *still* $\Bbb R\setminus\{-1,-2\}$. However, if both halves of the fraction were multiplied by $x+1$, $-1$ would no longer be outside the domain:
$$\frac{x+1}{1+1/(x+1)}=\frac{(x+1)^2}{x+2}$$
This shows that $-1$ is a removable singularity; $f$ may be assigned its limit there (zero) and it will remain regular around $-1$.

Comment: The continuity comment I made was misleading. I know it can be a removable singularity. I guess I was thinking in the context of the one-point compactification of the real line, where division by 0 is defined because it's unambiguous (like it isn't here). I'll think about it more, but you're almost certainly correct. I'm just getting tired.

Comment: You're absolutely correct. I'm just an idiot.